# Passing variables through two of the same foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop at the beginning of my document that is pulling data from an array and settings some variables to use later on. Let's say for this example `$foo` has **10 arrays** in it with keys of `ID` and `Name`.

```
foreach($foo as $bar) {
    $id = $bar['id'];
    $name = $bar['name'];
}
```

Then, what I'd like to do is, further along in my document where I actually want to display these results for each `$bar`, I'd like to do this.

```
foreach($foo as $bar) {
    // display all ids
    echo $id;
    // display all names
    echo $name;
}
```

But I am running into an issue.  When trying to display the IDs and Names in the second foreach loop, it's returning 10 cases of an ID, but the IDs are all the same, and it's the ID from the last array in `$foo`.

```
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
```

If I echo out the `$id` and `$name` in the first foreach loop, I see all 10 different names and ids.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Can I not call a second foreach loop on the same array? How would I go about doing this without throwing everything into a single foreach loop? I'd like to keep it organized and have the variables near the top, while outputting everything later on in the document.

Comment: Your first loop is simply creating two vars for id and name, and overwriting the values every iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although for this purpose you do not require two loops, but let's say you do, then your second loop should look like

```
foreach($foo as $bar) {
$id = $bar['id'];
$name = $bar['name'];
// display all ids
echo $id;
// display all names
echo $name;
}
```

Currently with every iteration you are assigning new values to your id and name variables and hence after the end of the loop you see the last ones.

Also just for the sake of argument if you need those two loops separately you could then create an array of values in first loop and use that in second loop. But again its a waste of resource, duplicating everything

```
$data=array();
foreach($foo as $bar) {
    $data[]["id"] = $bar['id'];
    $data[]["name"] = $bar['name'];
}
```

and then

```
foreach($data as $bar) {
$id = $bar['id'];
$name = $bar['name'];

echo $id;
echo $name;
}
```

But this is utterly needless

Comment: I think the problem is that he wants to create new variables, but he is just overwriting them, your example just prints their values... if I'm correct...

Comment: I'd like to set the variables and then just call them in later on in the document.  I am trying to avoid creating 5 of the same loops throughout the document.  One loop will get just the id and name, another will get a photo and caption, and another a post and timestamp for example.

Comment: @hankey I suppose what I am trying to do just wont work.  Thinking too much like it's Javascript.  I'll just create new foreach loops to grab what ever I need when I need it in the document.  Just trying to keep this thing clean and organized.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to display all the ids, then all the names?
If so, you could use the following example.

First loop would be.

```
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    $ids[] = $bar['id'];
    $names[] = $bar['name'];
}
```

Then instead of the second loop you could use.

```
echo explode($ids,",");
echo explode($names,",");
```